# Dart json.Encode adds a spurious bracket pair

Tags: dart

The following Dart code produces `({"date_required":null})` which looks to me like the outside bracket pair is incorrect and my go API rejects it with a decode error. I am expecting `{"date_required":null}`. How can I fix this?

```dart
  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
    if (_formKey.currentState?.fields['date_required']?.value != null) {
      dateRequired = _formKey.currentState?.fields['date_required']!.value;
    }

    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'date_required':
          dateRequired != null ? dateRequired!.formatDbDate() : null
    };

    String dateRequiredString = jsonEncode(data);
```

Comment: There should not be any situation in which `jsonEncode` adds parentheses.  Please post a minimal example that can reproduce the problem. `print(jsonEncode({'date_required': null}));` prints `{"date_required":null}`, so there's something else that you're doing.

Comment: What happens if you `print(data)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you print the string.

The `json.encode` or `jsonEncode` methods will not add parentheses. It's simply not part of its possible output for any input.
The wrapping parentheses must come from something you do between creating the string and printing it.

Wrapping parentheses can happen if you print an iterable, like `print([dataRequiredString].take(1))`
or maybe if you wrap it in a record, `var args = (dataRequiredString, ); print(args);`.

For the record, your conditional extraction of a value can be simplified to:

```dart
var state = _formKey.currentState!;
if (state.validate()) {
  dataRequired = state.fields['date_required']?.value;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
if 
(_formKey.currentState?.fields['date_required']?.value 
!= null) {
dateRequired = 
_formKey.currentState?.fields['date_required']!.value;
}

Map<String, dynamic> data = {
'date_required':
dateRequired != null ? 
dateRequired!.formatDbDate() : null
 };

 String dateRequiredString = jsonEncode(data).toString().replaceAll("(","").replaceAll(")","");
```